# Why is document.elementFromPoint affected by pointer-events: none?

Tags: javascript, css

If you use `document.elementFromPoint(x,y)`, and more than one element is located at the provided coordinates, it is supposed to return the topmost element (topmost in the visual stacking order, not the source code).

If the topmost element has `pointer-events: none` set in CSS, `document.elementFromPoint` does not see it. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bryandowning/k6G8M/) demonstrates the effect.

Is this intended behavior? It seems like the browser is firing a click event (a secret click event that doesn't fire attached click handlers or default behaviors) at the coordinates you provide to find the element. Is there any way to see how `document.elementFromPoint` is implemented in different browsers? It seems rather odd that a CSS property would effect the behavior of a completely unrelated DOM function.

I've only tested this in the latest Chrome. I'm certain every browser treats this differently. I'm mainly curious about webkit based browsers, but more info about other browsers is always welcome.

Comment: I agree with this query. Surely it should be possible to detect an element under a point even if pointer-events are set to none. At least make it an option

Comment: I just tested and it's possible to quickly set `pointer-events` to `all`, use `document.elementFromPoint` or `document.elementsFromPoint` and set `pointer-events` back to `none` to get the element/s at a certain position. Seems to cause no issues with hovering and clicking through, at least in Firefox.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[The specs](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/) tell us the element is determined through hit testing, so Chrome seems to be behaving properly here. Other browsers might do it differently, but if they're following the specs then you should expect that `pointer-events` would prevent it from functioning.

Later on in the specs, it mentions that hit testing isn't clearly defined by the W3C at this time. However, it's probably safe to assume that they're using at least something similar to the [common use of the term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-testing).